# How to solve $1/x = 1/a + 1/b$ to get $x = ab/(a + b)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm working through the first problem set in a text book. I have the question and the solution, however the solution gives no in between steps, only the final result.

The question is solve for $x$ in :

$$\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}$$

I could only get one step in:

$$x = x\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}\right)$$

The solution by the text book answers section is:

$$x = \frac{ab}{a + b}$$

How was this arrived at? Seeking the steps between to arrive at this?

Comment: The "one step" that you get is false. When you multiply both sides with $x$, the left hand side is $1$, not $x$. But this does not help : what helps is taking the reciprocals of both sides.

Comment: You have an error in your first step: it should read $1=x(1/a+1/b)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$$

$$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\color{red}b}{a\color{red}b}+\frac{\color{red}a}{b\color{red}a}$$

$$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{a+b}{ba}$$

$$x=\frac{ab}{a+b}$$

Comment: Sorry for being slow but I'm just not following the second line. How do you get to ```b/ab + a/ba```? From the comment under my post I Googled "reciprocals" which took me to this page but I don't see how it applies? https://www.mathsisfun.com/reciprocal.html

Comment: That's okay! Anything divided by itself is just $1$, so $b/b=1$ and $a/a=1$. That means we can multiply other fractions by $b/b$ and $a/a$ without changing the values of the original fractions, which is just what I did. I did that in order to get a common denominator ($ab$) in both fractions, which would then make it possible to add them.

Comment: It clicked thanks to your explanation. I think I got it. Those parts highlighted in red are are the equivalent of 1 while keeping the original denominator a and then b keeps the equation equivalent. OK, thanks a lot!

Comment: That's exactly it! Glad I could help!

Comment: One more follow up if that's OK. I understand how you arrived at this solution now but I wanted to try to find other exercises to make it sink in. I was not sure of what term to search for on Google for this. How did you know to use b/b and a/a? You must have recognized some pattern which indicated to do this? Does the approach you used here have a name?

Comment: I would search for something like "finding common denominators," because that's the essence of what I did. I saw that $x$ was in the denominator of the fraction on the left, so I knew that I could flip that fraction to get $x$ by itself. That would mean I would also have to flip whatever was on the other side of the equation, which works much better when the other side of the equation is a single fraction. If I hadn't combined $1/a$ and $1/b$ into a single fraction, I would have ended up with $$x=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}},$$ which is considerably uglier than $$x=\frac{ab}{a+b}$$

Comment: Of course, the "uglier" fraction can be simplified, as Jimmy showed, but I opted to do the simplification beforehand.

Comment: This helps, thanks again!

Comment: You're certainly welcome!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{b}{ab}+\frac{a}{ab}=\frac{a+b}{ab}$$ So $$\frac{1}{\frac1a+\frac1b}=\frac{1}{\frac{a+b}{ab}}=\frac{\frac11}{\frac{a+b}{ab}}=\frac{ab}{a+b}$$